# XAML Binding issues

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have spent the last three days trying to make this work, I don't really know how to do this, in short:

```
 <Grid DataContext="{Binding Path=Transaccion}">
    <DataGrid Name="tr" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fecha" Binding="{Binding Path=Transaccion.Fecha}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SubRubro.Nombre}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Monto}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=TipoTransaccion}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

`Transacciones` POCO has primary key which is referenced by `DetallesTransaccion`(Transaction details) in his `Transaccion_Id` column, this XAML I want all the references `DetallesTransaccion` referencing the same `Transaccion_Id` appearing in the `rowDetails`, now is appearing only one per `Transaccion`. Then I have another issue, that is related to data binding too and I cant get it to work either:

```
[Table("SubRubro")]
public class SubRubro
{  
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Codigo { get; set; }

    public string Nombre { get; set; }        

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }        

    public virtual SubRubro Parent { get; set; }
}
```

ALL `SubRubros` have a self-reference to the table in the `parentId` column, all `SubRubro`s have a direct parent, I cant make a visual representation of this I tried everything, `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, `DataTemplate`, here is a example of rows in my table:

```
ID   CODE       NAME             PARENTID

1   10.1      SubRubro 0           NULL(Dont have parent)
21  10.1.1    SubRubro anidado 0    1
22  10.1.2    SubRubro anidado 1    1
23  10.1.3    SubRubro anidado 2    1
24  10.1.1.1  SubRubro anidado 3    21
25  10.1.1.2  SubRubro anidado 4    21
```

Can you enlighten me?

**EDIT**
This is my Transactions class:

```
 public partial class Transaccion
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Transaccion()
    {
        DetallesTransaccion = new HashSet<DetallesTransaccion>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    public int AutorizaId { get; set; }

    public int ConfeccionaId { get; set; }

    public int CentroCostoId { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<DetallesTransaccion> DetallesTransaccion { get; set; }

    public virtual Usuario Autoriza { get; set; }

    public virtual Usuario Confecciona { get; set; }
}
```

Transaction Details:

```
public partial class DetallesTransaccion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int TransaccionId { get; set; }

    public int SubRubroId { get; set; }

    public decimal? Monto { get; set; }

    public TipoTransaccion TipoTransaccion { get; set; }

    public virtual SubRubro SubRubro { get; set; }

    public virtual Transaccion Transaccion { get; set; }
}

public enum TipoTransaccion
{
    Debita = 0,
    Acredita = 1
}
```

Viewmodel:(for testing)

```
    private NeotekDB ctx = new NeotekDB();

    public List<DetallesTransaccion> Transaccion
    {
        get { return ctx.DetallesTransaccion.Include("Transaccion").ToList(); }
    }

    public List<Transaccion> Detalles
    {
        get { return ctx.Transacciones.Include("DetallesTransaccion").ToList(); }
    }
```

Both queries are the same but differente entry points, trying to see if there is difference, but no. 
    **EDIT 2**
I am getting this:[image: THIS]

I want this: [image: Want this]

Comment: Follow a few MVVM WPF tutorials and you'll get the hang of it.  You need to be notifying your view of updates--INotifyPropertyChanged and ObservableableCollection are good for that--and you need to have the correct `DataContext` set for your controls.  Also, I what does your Transaction class look like? I have a feeling your `ItemsSource` binding isn't correct.

Comment: I cant get to display the values tha way I want since application starts, nothing to do with INPC

Comment: Take my advice.  Your ItemsSource should be bound to something like an `ObservableCollection<T>` and you should be adding items to it.  If the data exists before the application starts and you're not adding/removing, you need to set your DataContext before MainWindow's InitializeComponent() is called.

Comment: Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. State precisely what that code does and how that's different from what you want.

Comment: I set the DataContext with a ServiceLocator, and the view displays cause of a data template that points to that type of ViewModel, please give me advice of how to do the bindings to get what my last pictures says, i have to do something estrcitly in code to have what I want? should I bind to another property only getting details to bind to the details of a specific Transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step would be to parse your data into a set of objects that accurately represents your data hierarchy.

Depending on what kind of behavior or appearance you want, there's two ways of doing this.

Either parse into separate `Transaction` and `TransactionDetail` objects, like below :

```
public class Transaction
{
    // all properties related to Transaction
    public int TransaccionId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public int AutorizaId { get; set; }
    public int ConfeccionaId { get; set; }
    public int CentroCostoId { get; set; }
    public Usuario Autoriza { get; set; }
    public Usuario Confecciona { get; set; }

    // A list of the transaction detail objects for this transaction
    public List<TransactionDetail> TransactionDetails { get; set; }
}

public class TransactionDetail
{
    // all properties related to transaction detail record
    public int TransactionDetailId { get; set; }
    public decimal? Monto { get; set; }
    public TipoTransaccion TipoTransaccion { get; set; }
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }  

    // this could also be a Transaction object if needed
    public int ParentTransactionId { get; set; }
}
```

And draw your `List<Transactions>` with a DataGrid using a `DataGridTemplateColumn` to draw the the list of `TransactionDetails` however you want (ItemsControl, ListBox, etc).

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Transactions}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="TransaccionId" Binding="{Binding TransaccionId}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fecha" Binding="{Binding Fecha}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Descripcion" Binding="{Binding Descripcion}" />

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Details">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TransactionDetails}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

---

Or alternatively flatten your objects so each object contains the full set of both `TransactionDetail` and `Transaction` data, and set your DataGrid's grouping to group based on `TransactionId`.

Your data objects for the grid would then look something like this :

```
public class TransactionDetail
{
    // all properties related to Transaction
    public int TransaccionId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public int AutorizaId { get; set; }
    public int ConfeccionaId { get; set; }
    public int CentroCostoId { get; set; }
    public Usuario Autoriza { get; set; }
    public Usuario Confecciona { get; set; }

    // all properties related to transaction detail record
    public int TransactionDetailId { get; set; }
    public int ParentTransactionId { get; set; }
    public decimal? Monto { get; set; }
    public TipoTransaccion TipoTransaccion { get; set; }
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }  
}
```

And your XAML would probably look something similar to [this MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff407126(v=vs.100).aspx). (Sorry, don't feel like writing it all out here. There's a lot of examples of DataGrid Grouping online though).

This class could probably also be simplified to use the Transaction object too, and use `ParentTransaction.X` in the data bindings.

```
public class TransactionDetail
{
    // all properties related to transaction detail record
    public int TransactionDetailId { get; set; }
    public decimal? Monto { get; set; }
    public TipoTransaccion TipoTransaccion { get; set; }
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }  

    // all properties related to Transaction
    public Transaction ParentTransaction { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Rachel, thanks for your answer! I get it. Which is the better way to do the parsing?(for examlple,for performance reasons). Should I parse the data coming from the database in a linq query and return 2 fresh objects (Transaction2, TransactionDetails2), should I use the same objects. And lastly I see you took out : 
        DetallesTransaccion = new HashSet<DetallesTransaccion>();
why? and the ICollection?. they dont work in binding? or I have a bad design in my POCOS? THANKS again

Comment: Using My POCOS cant bind to grouped details for each Transaction =(, cant enter Transaction Details or any property, i lose binding in the listbox

Comment: @LuchoMansilla It depends on what you plan on doing with the UI - personally I would prefer the first option unless I had specific requirements which would make the other option better, such as grouped data summaries, selection behavior, etc. As for what data objects to use, that also depends on what you're doing. If you plan on having data change, you'll need to be sure your object models implement INotifyPropertyChanged. If you plan on detail records being dynamically added/removed, you'll want to be sure to use an ObservableCollection instead of a List or ICollection.

Comment: As for why your bindings aren't working, I would guess the DataContext is not setup correctly. I'd recommend downloading a tool like [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) so you can see what the DataContext of each UI object is at runtime, and that will probably tell you why your bindings aren't working.